# Add PHP DateInterval to MySQL value in query

Tags: mysql, datetime, dateinterval

I want to build a script that check for overdue schedules. Based on the creation date and the interval of the schedule it should get noted as overdue. For example I've created a schedule now, and with an interval of 0 months and 2 days (users can only select months and days). That means in 2 days it's overdue.

In PHP I save it as a DateInterval which is translated into something like this in the database: `+P00Y00M02DT00H00M00S`. Can I use the value in the database to add that to the creation date (normal MySQL DateTime type)? I am aware of the `DATE_ADD` function in MySQL but I'm not sure if I can use that.

I was hoping to do all the first checks in pure queries to prevent unnecessary checks in PHP again.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would suggest using php to add the interval to the start date and save the due date in the database. It makes the query for past-due items very easy to write.